# PKCE: Invalid Code Verifier

Tags: javascript, oauth2, pkce

I am trying to implement the PKCE flow into my SPA. I have read a bunch of documentation including the [salesforce docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5), [the RFC for PKCE flow](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636) and have watched [this step by step instruction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppFikweHxAQ) from a salesforce dev.

I can request an temporary authorization code just fine, logging in works and allowing access to salesforce from my SPA works. But, no matter what I try, I cannot get the code_verifier to work. The auth server keeps responding with an invalid code verifier error. `{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"invalid code verifier"}`

Pertinent details:

```
//oauth-utils.js

const sha256 = (buffer) =>{
    return require('crypto').createHash('sha256').update(buffer).digest();}

 const base64URLEncode = (str) => {
        return str.toString('base64').replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=/g, '');
    }

const codeVerifier = () => {
    return base64URLEncode(require('crypto').randomBytes(32).toString('hex'))}

const codeChallenge = base64URLEncode(sha256(codeVerifier()))


/** To run the program and generate the needed codes enter `node oauth-utils.js` in the project folder.

Output should be:
>>> code_verifier is randomString
>>> code_challenge is aDifferentRandomString
*/
```

For ease of repro I  made a separate endpoints.js file to easily build the needed auth links

```
//endpoints.js

const initialAuthRequest = (domain, clientId, codeChallenge ) => `https:${domain}.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=code&code_challenge=${codeChallenge}&code_challenge_method=S256&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8000/account/authorize`
const tokenRequestEndpoint = (domain, clientId, authCode, codeVerifier) => `https:${domain}.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=${clientId}&code=${authCode}&code_verifier=${codeVerifier}&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8000/account/authorize`

console.log(`plug this endpoint into postman and hit Send and Download, or you can navigate there in your browser as well: \n
${initialAuthRequest('my-domain.develop', 'myClientId', 'myCodeChallenge')} \n`);

console.log(`and here is the token request endpoint. Use a POST request here using the auth code you recieved after succesffuly registering \n
${tokenRequestEndpoint('my-domain.develop', 'myClientId', 'myAuthcode', 'myVerifier')}`);

/**
To run program enter `node endpoints.js` in the project folder.

Output should read
>>> plug this endpoint into postman and hit Send and Download, or you can navigate there in your browser as well:

>>> https:my-domain.develop.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=myClientId&response_type=code&code_challenge=myCodeChallenge&code_challenge_method=S256&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8000/account/authorize

>>> and here is the token request endpoint. Use a POST request here using the auth code you recieved after succesffuly registering 

>>> https:my-domain.develop.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=myClientId&code=myAuthcode&code_verifier=myVerifier&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8000/account/authorize
*/
```

The error I receive is this:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "invalid code verifier"
}
```

In terms of OAuth Permissions for the connected app, I have full access and refresh token access enabled.

Can anyone see what I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful. Your example is sufficiently minimal, not complete and therefore not reproducible.

Comment: Oh! Thank you - I will update my question to have it meet this standard

Comment: Updated - I tested it with these files and still same issue. @identigral